# I am getting a "Time Limit Exceeded " error in the following code. How to fix that error

Tags: python-3.x

The following code is my view of checking whether the sum of a number and it's reverse is a palindrome or not.If the sum is a palindrome then sum will be displayed.Otherwise the process will be repeated until we get a palindrome. When it is set to execute, I am getting a time limit exceeded error.Where do I need to correct the code?

```
def pal(n1):
    temp=n1
    rev=0
    while(temp>0):
        rev=(rev*10)+(temp%10)
        temp=temp/10
    sum1=n1+rev
    temp=sum1
    rev=0
    while(temp>0):
        rev=(rev*10)+(temp%10)
        temp=temp/10
    if(rev==sum1):
        print(sum1)
    else:
        pal(sum1)


n=int(input())
pal(n)
```

I expect the output of a number `453` to be `6666`. 
i.e.

- `453+354=807` (not a palindrome. So repeat the process)
- `807+708=1515`
- `1515+5151=6666` (it is a palindrome)

Comment: why aren't you using string manipulation for this? Also, perhaps you could spend a few words on what is the idea behind your algorithm...

Comment: Anyway your code has an infinite loop and the *time limit exceeded* is probably because you are running it in some service with limited wall time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are checking for `while temp > 0:` but inside that loop you are using *float division*: `temp=temp/10`. So the condition will always hold. For example:

```py
>>> 8/10
0.8
>>> 0.8/10
0.08
```

What you want is to change your divisions to *int division*:

```py
>>> 8//10
0
```

Still you might consider working with strings which is much easier in that case:

```py
def pal(n):
    rev_n = str(n)[::-1]
    sum_str = str(n + int(rev_n))
    while sum_str != sum_str[::-1]:
        # print(sum_str)
        sum_rev = sum_str[::-1]
        sum_str = str(int(sum_str) + int(sum_rev))
    print(sum_str)
```

And with the commented print this gives:

```py
>>> pal(453)
807
1515
6666
```

Comment: nice spotting the bug, but not so nice *proposed approach*

Comment: why is that not nice?

Comment: This version is better, but with this one you are still modifying the input even if it is already a palindrome. Also, it is not good style to write a function with side effects if you can write one without (i.e. use return instead of print at the end).

Comment: As for the print I was simply going with OP's direction (as there is no return in his function I cannot know what are the requirements of the function) and as I understand from the question you are never checking whether the input is a palindrome rather its sum with its own reverse

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this using string manipulation, which goes a lot easier than trying to do this with numbers. It is also a more direct translation of what you describe afterwards. (I do not really see the link between your code and your description...)

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    # : approach1, faster for large inputs
    # mid_length = len(text) // 2
    # offset = 0 if len(text) % 2 else 1
    # return text[:mid_length] == text[:-mid_length - offset:-1]

    # : approach2, faster for small inputs
    return text == text[::-1]


def palindrome_sum(num):
    while not is_palindrome(num):
        num = str(int(num) + int(num[::-1]))
    return num


num = input()  # 453
palindrome = palindrome_sum(num)
print(palindrome)
# 6666
```